# Form submit button not working on mobile (iPhone and iPad)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

The form on a webpage I'm working on works perfectly on desktop, but will not work on mobile (iPad and iPhone). When you tap the "submit message" button, nothing happens. The confirmation message does not appear and I do not get an email (using nodemailer on the back end to send me an email). I've tried the following:

- using same 'submit' event listener on the form on both desktop and mobile
- adding an event listener on the button for the 'touchend' event for mobile
- using the onsubmit property in the HTMLFormElement object rather than using the event listener

Here is the HTML:

```
<section id="contactContainer">
  <section id="form"><a id="contact"></a>
    <h2>Contact Me</h2>
    <form action="/formSubmission" method="post">
      <label for="reason">Reason for reaching out:</label>
      <select name="reason">
        <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
        <option value="Web Development">Web Development</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
      </select><br>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" class="name" required>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" class="name" required>
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company" required><br>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required><br>
      <textarea name="message" placeholder="Let me know what you're looking for."></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit">
    </form>
  </section>

  <section id="confirmation">
    <h2>Thanks for sending! I'll be in touch shortly.</h2>
  </section>
</section>
```

And the vanilla JS:

```
var form = document.querySelector('form'),
    button = document.querySelector('form input[name="submit"]'),
    confirmation = document.querySelector('#confirmation h2'),
    formSection = document.querySelector('#form');

form.addEventListener('submit', submit);
button.addEventListener('touchend', submit);

function sortFormData(form) {
  var parsedForm = {},
      elements = [...form.elements];


  elements.forEach(element => {
    if(element.name) { 
      parsedForm[element.name] = element.value;
    }
  })

  return JSON.stringify(parsedForm);
}


//Form confirmation

HTMLElement.prototype.makeTransparent = function() {
  this.style.opacity = 0;
  this.style['z-index'] = 0;
}

HTMLElement.prototype.appear = function() {
  this.style['z-index'] = 1;
  this.style['font-size'] = '0px';
  this.style.opacity = 1;

  if(this.style['font-size'] === '0px') {
    console.log('Animation start.');
  }

  this.classList.add('submitted');
}

//Helper function

function submit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = sortFormData(form);
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
  request.open('POST', './formSubmission', true);
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
  request.send(formData);

  formSection.makeTransparent();
  confirmation.appear();
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check if the event handler fired first on mobile and tablet. If the function works fine on desktop but not on mobile, I think it's very likely that the click event is not triggered at all on mobile devices.

It's likely that a style problem or something similar makes your button stays under some other HTML elements in mobile/tablet and when you tab on the button, a click event is not triggered.

You can figure it out by using Developer tool in the browser and inspect the button area on a mobile view.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what this was. I was using the spread operator in the sortFormData function that stopped submission in its tracks. When I updated the code, it worked perfectly. New code:

```
function sortFormData(form) {
  var parsedForm = {};
  var elements = Array.prototype.map.call(form, function(ele) {
    return ele;
  });


  elements.forEach(element => {
    if(element.name) { 
      parsedForm[element.name] = element.value;
    }
  })

  return JSON.stringify(parsedForm);
}
```